# Custom taxonomy throw error 404

Tags: custom-taxonomy, 404-error

So in my homework I was given code example and it works for teacher, but not for me. So from what i understand that I'm creating custom post type and custom taxonomy for it, also there is filter that replaces my %gaming_genre_new% with created category. And it works on custom post type stage, but it breaks when I add taxonomy. I can access for example my archive "gaming" and even created with taxonomy "genres" in it, but when i want to view particular post, it just throws error 404.

```php
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomy' );
function create_taxonomy(){

    register_taxonomy( 'gaming_genre_new', [ 'gaming' ], [
        'label'                 => '', // определяется параметром $labels->name
        'labels'                => [
            'name'              => 'Game genres',
            'singular_name'     => 'Game genre',
            'search_items'      => 'Search Genres',
            'all_items'         => 'All Genres',
            'view_item '        => 'View Genre',
            'parent_item'       => 'Parent Genre',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Genre:',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit Genre',
            'update_item'       => 'Update Genre',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Genre',
            'new_item_name'     => 'New Genre Name',
            'menu_name'         => 'Genre',
            'back_to_items'     => '← Back to Genre',
        ],
        'description'           => '', // описание таксономии
        'public'                => true,
        // 'publicly_queryable'    => null, // равен аргументу public
        // 'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
        // 'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
        // 'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        // 'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        // 'show_in_quick_edit'    => null, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'hierarchical'          => true,

        'rewrite'               => array('slug'=>'gaming/%gaming_genre_new%','with_front'=>'false'),
        //'query_var'             => $taxonomy, // название параметра запроса
        'capabilities'          => array(),
        'meta_box_cb'           => null, // html метабокса. callback: `post_categories_meta_box` или `post_tags_meta_box`. false — метабокс отключен.
        'show_admin_column'     => false, // авто-создание колонки таксы в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
        'show_in_rest'          => null, // добавить в REST API
        'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
        // '_builtin'              => false,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    ] );
}


// создание своего типа записи 
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
function register_post_types(){
    register_post_type( 'gaming', [
        'label'  => null,
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => 'Gaming', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Gaming', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Add Gaming Post', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Adding Gaming Post', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit Gaming Post', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'New Gaming Post', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'View Gaming Post', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Search Gaming Post', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'Gaming', // название меню
        ],
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
        // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
        // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        // 'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // зависит от show_in_menu
        'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'menu_icon'           => null,
        //'capability_type'   => 'post',
        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'supports'            => [ 'title', 'editor', 'author'], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
        'taxonomies'          => ['gaming_genre_new'],
        'has_archive'         => 'gaming',
        'rewrite'             => array('slug'=>'gaming/%gaming_genre_new%','with_front' => 'false'),
        'query_var'           => true,
    ] );
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'gaming_permalink', 1,2);
function gaming_permalink($permalink,$post){
    if (strpos( $permalink, '%gaming_genre_new%' ) === false )
        return $permalink;
    
    $terms=get_the_terms($post,'gaming_genre_new');
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
    $term_slug=array_pop($terms)->slug;
    else
    $term_slug='no-gaming-genre';
    return str_replace('%gaming_genre_new%',$term_slug,$permalink);
}
```

UPD: forgot to mention that i tried: resetting permalinks and flush_rewrite_rules. And that I'm using openserver.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple: remove %gaming_genre_new% from rewrite for taxonomy, so it looks like this:

```php
'rewrite'               => array('slug'=>'gaming','with_front'=>'false'),
```

Now I wonder why original code worked for my friend and for my teacher...